# What's the download size of Restore and Update for iPad via iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipad

If you plugin your iPad to your PC and choose to reset it, and iTunes wants to Update and Restore your iPad, how much data will it download?

Comment: This all depends on the version of iPad you are using, the country you are located in, and whether your device is Wifi only or Wifi and cellular. I would guess that the downloads average about 2Gb from previous experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.8 GB for iPad (2016-1-22). The downloaded file is actually located in `\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPad Software Updates`

The location on Windows 10 is:

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Packages\AppleInc.iTunes_xxxx\LocalCache\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPad Software Updates
```

Answer (score 0):

The download size (2015-09-12) is 2 GB.

I measured how much data iTunes used when I reset my iPad.